# android-support-v7-appcompat project not importing in eclipse

Tags: android

I am trying to import the `android-support-v7-appcompat` project but I am getting a error **** project,but in case of other support library its working fine.

here are the steps

1. Select File > Import.
2. Select Existing Android Code Into Workspace and click Next.
3. Browse to the SDK installation directory and then to the Support
   Library folder. For example, if you are adding the appcompat
   project, browse to `<sdk>/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/`.
4. Click Finish to import the project. For the v7 appcompat project, you should now see a     new project titled android-support-v7-appcompat.

But I am not able to click on finish and getting the error  **select at least one project**.

here is the screen:
[image]

Comment: Check if your directory is not empty.

Comment: Check if android-support-v7-appcompat is already in your workspace.

Comment: ya you are write.Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

android-support-v7-appcompat is already in your workspace.

You can check that importing the android-support-v7-appcompat in another Workspace

Comment: Thanks! In my case, I already had a project named android-support-v7-appcompat hidden in another Working Set.  I wish Eclipse would warn better about this.